# ASP.Net authentication timeout issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I want to show a popup warning before authentication & session timeout.Warning popup should have option to either keep sign in or sign out. I am almost done with functionality but sometimes clicking on keep sign in button redirects user to log in page.
I have set same authentication & session time out value. 
I am using [timeout](http://rigoneri.github.io/timeout-dialog.js/) plugin to show warning. 
This is how my code looks like

```
timer = null;
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

        SetTimeoutDialog();
    });

    // show warning message to users before session timeout
    function SetTimeoutDialog() {

    //clear previous timers
        if (timer != null)
            clearInterval(timer);

        $.get('/GetRemainingTimeout.aspx', function (data) {
            var timeout = parseInt(data);
            timer = setInterval(function () {
                $.timeoutDialog({ timeout: 0, countdown: 180, keep_alive_url: '/KeepSessionAlive.aspx', logout_url: '/Logout.aspx', logout_redirect_url: '/Login.aspx', restart_on_yes: false });
            }, (timeout - 180000));
        });
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        SetTimeoutDialog();
    }
```

Also, this is how code in GetRemainingTimeout.aspx.cs looks like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            {
                HttpCookie authCookie = this.Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                double leftMilliSeconds = (authTicket.Expiration - dateNow).TotalMilliseconds;
                // Control in MasterPage, where I setting value and then taking for JavaSript to CountDown message
                Response.Write(leftMilliSeconds > 0 ? leftMilliSeconds.ToString() : "0");
            } 
        }
```

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net